# Raspberry Pi - UART - disable TX and enable RX in program C

Tags: c, uart, raspberry-pi4

I need connect my raspberry pi 4 model b with a servo via UART, but it is possible only via 1 wire. That means I must connect pin TX and RX together. In order to do so, I must have a way how to manually disable only TX or RX in my C program.

I am able to easily disable RX thanks to termios.h library, but I didn't find any way how to disable TX.

I was trying to disable it through this

```
tcflow(fd_myUART, TCOOFF); // it should suspend output
```

But that didn't work, so I thought that maybe if I change the pin of TX to INPUT, it will change the pin from UART to GPIO, but that didn't work either.

Do you have a way, how to do that, please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just "randomly" connecting both wires is a bad idea.
Below image shows how to do it better for a prototype.
Slave devices are able to pull the IO line low during a read bit or a reset while the TX signal is high.

[image]

When used in this configuration, you should not disable RX nor TX. You can use "normal" UART operation.

More information can be found [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/214.html) (maxim integrated tutorial 214 "USING A UART TO IMPLEMENT A 1-WIRE BUS MASTER")

Comment: This could work, but I'm a little concerned, because I will attach 30 servos to 1 raspberry pi and the baud rate must be up to 1 000 000 or 2 000 000. I'm worried about the baud rate in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have a lot of connected slave, you should consider using a dedicated chip:

I use a [DS2482S-100](https://www.artekit.eu/resources/ak-ds2482s-100/doc/AK-DS2482S-100-Rev1.pdf) over I2C.